# Reconstructing satellite sensor swath polygon (multiple orbits, antimeridian crossing)

Tags: qgis, r, satellite, antimeridian

I'm currently working on a project that involves displaying a given satellite's sensor coverage of Earth, with one of the objective being to count how many swaths overlap a given point on Earth over a period of time.

The way I identified to do this was to get polygons of the sensor swath bounds over the considered period of time (screenshot below from ESA's ESOV-NG software, showing 3 orbits of Sentinel-3A and the OCLI sensor swath in red).

[image]

For the sake of the example, let's take ISS and strap an hypothetical sensor on it. To provide reproducible data, you can find a plot of its track for around 5 hours, enough for it to perform about 3 orbits of the Earth. The following steps examples here won't focus on the sensor swath geometry method, I will use a simple distance/bearing from the orbit plot to determine the swath bounds).

Example data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YhmjQsuVpfwd9fZN6K8X9WTmzMGlpCxP/view?usp=sharing

```r
library(sf)
library(geosphere)

orbit = st_read("./iss.geojson")

   velocity  heading altitude longitude FID   latitude                    geometry
1  7.658051 141.2064 422.7336 -1.275365   0  -8.137724 POINT (-1.275211 -8.137684)
2  7.657012 140.2421 424.1191  3.215159   1 -14.169493  POINT (3.215313 -14.16945)
3  7.655892 138.6951 425.7888  7.972243   2 -20.087314  POINT (7.972397 -20.08728)
(...)
```

```r
# Using simplified method for sensor swath: bounds are 90 degrees left of right
# of the satellite's heading at a given orbit subpoint, here 400 km off-nadir
swathLeft = geosphere::destPoint(st_coordinates(orbit), orbit[["heading"]] - 90, 400000) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('lon', 'lat'), crs = 4326)

swathRight = geosphere::destPoint(st_coordinates(orbit), orbit[["heading"]] + 90, 400000) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c('lon', 'lat'), crs = 4326)

# Giving each point an ID in sequence for future reconstruction of
# swath line or polygon bound, ordered by ID
swathLeft[["FID"]] = as.integer(seq.int(nrow(swathLeft)) - 1)
swathRight[["FID"]] = as.integer(2 * (nrow(swathRight)) - seq.int(nrow(swathRight)))

swathBounds = rbind(swathLeft, swathRight) %>% 
  st_write("swathBounds.shp")
```

At this point, I have my left and right bounds of my swath along the orbit track. My next steps would then be to build the swath bounding polygon from those points. For this I would go in QGIS and successively use `Points to path` (sorting by FID order) and `Lines to Polygons` tools.

This is working well with a small set of orbit track points that are not crossing the antimeridian. For instance, here is the result for the first 23 subpoints of ISS' track (`issShort.geojson` in the data set):

QGIS `Points to path (order by FID)` > `Lines to Polygons`:
[image]

However things get complicated when the orbit crosses the antimeridian and/or there are several full orbits. A thought I had was to reproject the swath bounds points to an azimutal projection (i.e. `EPSG:3571`) , in order to avoid dealing with the antimeridian. I would then split the polygons at the antimeridian line before reprojecting back to `EPSG:4326`. However, when building from lines to polygons, the polygons are built so that they do not overlap, in order to ensure the geometry in valid - generating holes in my swaths. This is a good thing in general use cases... but for me it is a problem! Here are the results.

```r
swathBounds = rbind(swathLeft, swathRight) %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 3571) %>% 
  st_write("swathBounds.shp")
```

QGIS `Points to path` (order by FID) > `Lines to Polygons`:

[image]

The next steps, splitting the polygons with the antimeridian line, give obviously corrupted results:

QGIS `Split with lines` (split with `antimed.shp` line) > `Reproject layer` (to `EPSG:4326`):

[image]

Not only the geometry glitches, but the returned object is a single polygon, whereas the objective to split it at the antimeridian was to have one polygon for a swath ranging from -180 to +180 longitude (i.e. one full orbit = one swath polygon).

So, my workflow is definitely missing something. Any input with regards to handling that geometry itself, or any suggestion of an alternative method? I try to be tool agnostic, though I prefer using `R`, `Python` and/or `QGIS` for that purpose.

For interested people, I use the `Ground Track Generator` CLI tool to generate the orbit plots (https://github.com/anoved/Ground-Track-Generator). Another handy tool for this is Python `skyfield` library.